# Nice way of showing the locus of $\left|z-\frac{1}{z}\right| = 2$ is the union of 2 intersecting circles.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry

For visualisation, the following code was run in Mathematica.

`ContourPlot[{Abs[x + I y - 1/(x + I y)] == 2}, {x, -2.42, 2.42}, {y, -2.42, 2.42}, Axes -> True]`

Here is the locus plot generated by the above code.

[image]

I do not see a nice way of showing the locus is what is is apart from brute force algebraic factorisation, which basically requires knowing the form of the locus *a priori*.

A less cumbersome approach is desired, if such a method exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can bring a little geometry into the picture.

First render

$|z+1|^2|z-1|^2=4|z|^2$

by algebraic methods as explained in other answers.  Now draw the quadrilateral whose vertices are $\pm 1, \pm z$.  This is a parallelogram, meaning the sum of its squared diagonal equals the sum of all four squared sides.  Thereby

$4|z|^2+4=2(|z+1|^2+|z-1|^2)$

Eliminating $|z|^2$ between these two equations and collecting all terms to one side then leads to:

$|z+1|^2|z-1|^2-2(|z+1|^2+|z-1|^2)+4=0$

which is factorable!

$\color{blue}{(|z+1|^2-2)(|z-1|^2-2)=0}$

The union of circles then follows.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\left|z-{1\over z}\right|=2
&\iff|z-1||z+1|=2|z|\\
&\iff((x-1)^2+y^2)((x+1)^2+y^2)=4(x^2+y^2)\\
&\iff(x^2+y^2+1-2x)(x^2+y^2+1+2x)=4(x^2+y^2)\\
&\iff(x^2+y^2+1)^2-4x^2=4(x^2+y^2)\\
&\iff(x^2+y^2-1)^2-4x^2=0
\end{align}$$

On the other hand, the equation for the locus of two circles of radius $r$, centered at $(x,y)=(\pm c,0)$, is

$$((x-c)^2+y^2-r^2)((x+c)^2+y^2-r^2)=0$$

This can be rewritten as

$$(x^2+y^2+c^2-r^2)^2-4c^2x^2=0$$

All we need is to let $c=1$ and $r=\sqrt2$.

Comment: how... Did you "magically" write Those expressions, I mean HOW? I followed till here $$\begin{align}
\left|z-{1\over z}\right|=2
&\iff|z-1||z+1|=2|z|\\
&\iff((x-1)^2+y^2)((x+1)^2+y^2)=4(x^2+y^2)\\
&\iff(x^2+y^2+1-2x)(x^2+y^2+1+2x)=4(x^2+y^2) \end{align}$$

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20-, I'm not sure what you mean by "till here." Which step(s) do you find hard to follow?

Comment: both steps after that. Actually, I did figure out how you got to the last step(final result) from previous but I couldn't have spotted it. I don't understand how you "merged" the two terms in brackets (in multiplication). I can Obviously"verify" it by expanding but how did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary:

$|z-1|^2+|z+1|^2\\=(z-1)(\bar z-1)+(z+1)(\bar z+1)\\=|z|^2-2\,\Re(z)+1+|z|^2+2\,\Re(z)+1\\=2|z|^2+2\tag{Eq1}$

With that we can transform our original equation:

$|z-\frac 1z|=2\iff |z^2-1|^2=4|z|^2$ and there is equivalence because moduli are positive numbers.

We can then factorize

$(|z-1|^2-2)\times(|z+1|^2-2)=|z^2-1|-2(\text{Eq1})+4=4|z|^2-2(2|z|^2+2)+4=0$

In the end we conclude:

> $$|z-\frac 1z|=2\iff |z-1|=\sqrt{2}\quad \text{or}\quad|z+1|=\sqrt{2}$$

Which is the union of two circles.

Comment: Minor quibble: $z+\bar z=2\Re(z)$, not $\Re(z)$ (not that it matters, since the cancellation happens anyway).

Comment: In fact I originally went for a different path than yours, I wanted to consider the $\frac{MA}{MB}=k$ characterization of a circle. And in fact $\frac{|z-1|}{|z|}=\sqrt{2}$ (with $A=(-1,0)$ and $B=(0,0)$) and $|z+1|=\sqrt{2}$ both define the same circle. My idea was then to multiply the equations to get the result. But as I said, it was the same circle, and I need $|z-1|=\sqrt{2}$ for the other one. But then multiplying doesn't work. This is why in the end I went for $(|z-1|-r)(|z+1|+r)=0$ instead. Just to notice that finally it was just a slightly modified version of your answer...