# Let $z\in\mathbb{C}, z\ne0$, if $\left|z-\frac{1}{z}\right|=2$, then what is the maximum value of $|z| ?$(Solve preferably without using geometry)

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z$ be a non-zero complex number such that $\left|z-\frac{1}{z}\right|=2$. What is the maximum value of $|z| ?$ (Solve preferably without using geometry.)

**My attempt:**

I tried to simplify things down by writing $\left|z-\frac{1}{z}\right|=2$ as $$\left(z-\frac 1z\right)\overline{\left(z-\frac 1z\right)}=\left(z-\frac 1z\right)\left(\overline z -\frac1{\overline z}\right)=4\implies |z|^2+\frac 1{|z|^2}+\frac{z}{\overline z}+\frac {\overline z}{z}=4.$$

But then, I am getting stuck at this step in the hope of proceeding with a breakthrough.

Then I tried using some standard inequalities:

$$|z|-\left|\frac 1z\right|\leq \left|z-\frac 1z\right|$$ and $$\left|z-\frac 1z\right|\leq |z|+\left|\frac 1z\right|$$

But this doesn't help much either.

Also, I tried writing $z=re^{i\theta}$ and neither does this make things easy. Till now, I am unable to find any major breakthrough. I am not interested in a geometric solution.

I think the link [$|z-1/z|=2$ where $z$ is a complex number. How to find the greatest value of $|z|$ geometrically?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437832/z-1-z-2-where-z-is-a-complex-number-how-to-find-the-greatest-value-of-z) asks for a geometrical solution specifically. But, I wanted a regular algebraic, approach to this problem. So, I am not sure if my post can be considered a duplicate or not as both of the posts, though focus on the same question, but the desired approach of the solution method (to the problem) , are different. (As, of now, I tried to make it specific in this post of mine to avoid further confusion)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3173917/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1618068/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! I indeed found a better approach to this problem on the linked page you suggested. But how did you locate the duplicate? Any special software you are using ?

Comment: @MartinR Though, I would add that the question specifically asked for a geometrical approach, while I wanted a regular, simple algebraic approach. So can it be called, a duplicate ?

Comment: I found those [with Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969). There are various answers in that Q&A (geometric and other approaches) to that it qualifies as a duplicate target IMO. Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1618068/42969) which is the same task just with a slightly different parameter.

Comment: @MartinR I used Approach0 too, but couldn't find any. Maybe, the reason could be, that I typed out insufficient keywords. This happened to me a few days back as well. Yeah, there might be some which is a duplicate of this one. I am not sure, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$, then you get

$$|r^2e^{2i\theta}-1|=2r$$

expand, we get

$$r^4-2r^2\cos2\theta+1=4r^2$$

Move terms,

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(r^2+\frac{1}{r^2}\right)=2+\cos2\theta$$

For LHS, the minimum value is $1$, when $r=1$, and we want $r$ to be as large as possible, apparently, $r_{max}=r_m>1$

For $r\in[1,\infty)$, the LHS is monotonic increasing, so the maximum value occures when the RHS reaches its maxima, so we get:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(r_m^2+\frac{1}{r_m^2}\right)=2+1\Rightarrow r_m^2=3\pm2\sqrt2$$

Since $r_m>1$, we get

$$r_m=\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}=\sqrt2+1$$

Comment: Certain parts of your answer still seems unclear to me. $(1)$ First of all, when you wrote, "For LHS, the minimum value is $1$, when $r=1$, and we want $r$ to be as large as possible, apparently, $r_{max}=r_m>1$", I understand, that the arithmetic mean of $(r^2,\frac 1{r^2}$ is minimum at $r=1,$ and for $|z|=r$ (when $z=re^{i\theta}$ to be maximum, the value of $r$ should be optimised (or better, be increased) so as to $|z|$ maximum. But I don’t understand, why you claimed $r_{max}=r_m>1$, from the fact that "the arithmetic mean of $(r^2,\frac 1{r^2})$ is minimum at $r=1$ "? I think

Comment: it follows from the fact, that *As, the square root of a positive real is defined to be positive,* so, $r=\sqrt{r^2}\geq 0$. Now, $r\neq 0$ as then $|z|$ is minimum as $z$ is at origin. So, $r\gt 0$. The function $f(r)=\sqrt {r^2}$ is monotonically increasing when $r\in (0,\infty),$ $r$ variable cannot be particularly optimised to a fixed real number so that $r$ is maximum.

Comment: My question number $(2)$: The thing that $|z|$ depends only on $r$$\implies$ $\theta$ variable need not be optimised as $|z|$ does not depend on $\theta$. So, wouldn't the maximum value of $|z|\to\infty$ ?

Comment: when $r=1$, the LHS equals $1$, if you look at RHS, the range is $[1, 3]$, which means, as long as the LHS is within $[1, 3]$, you can always find an angle $\theta$ to make this equation hold. For example, if you move $r$ slightly larger than $1$, say $1+\delta$ due to the continuity of LHS, its value will be slightly larger than $1$, say $1.1$, and $1.1\in[1,3]$, so you can find $\theta$ to make this equation hold. Hence you find a candidate for $r_m$, which is $1+\delta$, so I say $r_m>1$.

Comment: Now, that's a nice logical argument you gave. So, what you did was you tried finding  a candidate so that RHS is $3$ ? But implicitly didn't you ise the fact, that as $2+\cos \theta$ increases $r$ increases as well ? If you used this implicitly, then I want to know, how did you know this fact was true ?

Comment: No, I just narrow down $r$ from $(0, \infty)$ into $[1, \infty)$, because on $[0, \infty)$, the LHS is not monotonic. But on $[1, \infty)$, the LHS is monotonic.

Comment: Did you comment this with reference to my previous comment? I am saying this, because I edited my earlier comment. I want to know, whether you used that fact, I stated. Because, it seems that it's used.

Comment: I write this again in hopes of avoiding unwanted confusions: It seems that you tried, finding a candidate for $r_m$ so that R.H.S becomes maximum,i.e when RHS is $3$. Now, as you suggest rightly, that L.H.S is monotonically increasing function in $[1,\infty)$ so, to make the range of L.H.S valid and maximum, the R.H.S should be optimised to maximum, isn't it? And R.H.S would be optimised only when , value of R.H.S is increased to the greatest possible value $3$ and hence, the maximum possible candidate for $r_m$ is when LHS increases to $3$ **because, as $r$ increases, LHS increases**

Comment: and the maximum possible $LHS$ is $3$ so, the permitted maximization of $r$ should be such that $LHS$ is $3$ and this is what you did ?

Comment: Let $f(r)=LHS$, If you start from the lowest point $r=1$, as $2+\cos\theta$ increases, $r$ can either increase or decrease, for example, $f(0.8)>f(1), f(1.2)>f(1)$, due to the fact $f$ is decreasing on $(0, 1)$ and increasing on $[1,\infty)$. So you need to first exclude the interval $(0, 1)$, so I said $r_m$ is obviously greater than $1$. So now you can only consider the interval $[1,\infty)$, and on this interval the function $f$ is increasing. So you just simply let the $RHS=3$ and solve for $r$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145935/discussion-between-stephen-smith-and-mathfail).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, following your first idea without exponential form

$$\left(z-\frac 1z\right)\overline{\left(z-\frac 1z\right)}=\left(z-\frac 1z\right)\left(\overline z -\frac1{\overline z}\right)=4\iff |z|^2+\frac 1{|z|^2}\color{red}-\frac{z}{\overline z}\color{red}-\frac {\overline z}{z}=4$$

we have

$$\iff |z|^2+\frac 1{|z|^2}-2=\frac{z}{\overline z}+\frac {\overline z}{z}+2\iff \left(|z|-\frac1{|z|}\right)^2=\frac{z^2}{|z|^2}+\frac {\overline z^2}{|z|^2}+2$$

$$\iff \left(|z|-\frac1{|z|}\right)^2=\left(\frac{z}{|z|}+\frac {\overline z}{|z|}\right)^2\iff \left(|z|-\frac1{|z|}\right)^2=\frac{(z+\bar z)^2}{|z|^2}$$

with $(z+\bar z)=2|z|\cos \theta$ then last identity is equivalent to

$$\left(|z|-\frac1{|z|}\right)^2 =4\cos^2 \theta$$

and $|z|$ is maximum for $\cos^2 \theta =1$ that is

$$\left(|z|-\frac1{|z|}\right)^2 =4\implies |z|_{\text{max}}=\sqrt 2 +1$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well here's a generalized formula for your question;

$$\left|z ± \frac{b}{z}\right|=a$$ where a and b are constants;

Maximum and minimum values of $|Z|$ are

$$max =  \frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4|b|}}{2}$$

$$min =  \frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+4|b|}}{2}$$

Comment: using triangular inequality